# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 Max(Int64, Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, runtime-error

I'm getting this error message during runtime

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 Max(Int64, Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

when I try to do this:

```
return _dbContext.Appointment.Where(x => Math.Max(x.Appointment.StartTime.Ticks, startTime.Ticks) <= Math.Min(x.Appointment.EndTime.Ticks, endTime.Ticks));
```

The idea behind this query is that "if the latest start time is before the earliest end time, then you have some overlap/touching" in date and time.

Is there any way to get this line working? I already checked if `EntityFunctions` has 'something', which wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always keep in mind that every IQueryable provider is implemented in its own way. That query would work in Linq to Objects (as it does not gets translated to anything) but may or may not work in IQueryable providers.

In your specific case, it's telling you that it has no idea on how to translate Math.Max and Math.Min into SQL commands. And that's perfectly correct, since EF doesn't recognize those methods.

In my opinion the easiest way to accomplish what you need is reading the max and the min value with two different queries and then do your logic in plain c#. Something like this:

```
var min = mycontext.MyDbSet.Min(c => c.Field);
var max = mycontext.MyDbSet.Max(c => c.Field);
if (max <= min)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: But in your example, Min and Max selects only one 'Field'. And I need to know which one is the bigger one of 2 fields. The start time stored in the database and the start time passes as a parameter. Same goes for end time. How would I accomplish that with your example?

Comment: As I mentioned, get what you need from the db, and do all the other computation in c#, outside of the db context. If what you intend to do cannot be translated by EF into a SQL command, that's the only way.

Comment: I misunderstood your example. So I'd need to select the 2 `DateTime` fields from the db and compare that against the passed parameters.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My code was just a proof of concept, not the final solution. :)

Answer (score 5):

`Max` and `Min` can be implemented like this:

```
public static long Max(long a, long b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}
public static long Min(long a, long b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

Since LINQ to Entities [understands](http://brandonatkinson.blogspot.com/2011/01/using-ifelse-in-your-linq-query.html) [`? :`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), you will be able to inline these into your expression. Also, since `Ticks` is not supported, but `DateTime` comparison is...

```
Math.Max(x.Appointment.StartTime.Ticks, startTime.Ticks)
```

Becomes

```
(x.Appointment.StartTime < startTime ? startTime : x.Appointment.StartTime)
```

Comment: Seems that Matteo Mosca's example is the way to go. This is the next runtime error msg i get using your example: "The specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}.

Comment: I've tested it and it seems that this query does not return the results I expected. I have to use a 3rd party library for it. Thanks for your help! +1