# Convert string to long type and use in a linq query within asp.net MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

How to convert string to long type in linq query.

My current code it give me this following error

> *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.*

**MY CODE IS LOOK LIKE THIS**

```
    var query = (from _employerdetails in _entities.Organisations
                 select new EmployerDetails
                 {
                     Id = _employerdetails.Id,
                     RefNo = _employerdetails.Refno,
                     Surname = _employerdetails.Surname,
                     TradingName = _employerdetails.TradingName,
                     CompanyRegistrationNumber = _employerdetails.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                     PhysicalAddress = _employerdetails.BusAddr1,
                     PostalAddress = _employerdetails.BusPostalAddr1,
                     Status = _employerdetails.Status,
                     SETACode = _employerdetails.SetaCode,
                     TransactionDate = ( from _lasttransaction in _entities.LevyTransactions
                                         where Convert.ToInt64(_lasttransaction.OrgId) ==_employerdetails.Id
                                         select _lasttransaction.TransactionDate).Max()
                 });
```

Help me please guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 Max(Int64, Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124923/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int64-maxint64-int64-method)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the conversion outside the query.

```
long OrgId = Convert.ToInt64(_lasttransaction.OrgId);
```

So your query will be like

```
var query = (from _employerdetails in _entities.Organisations
                 select new EmployerDetails
                 {
                     Id = _employerdetails.Id,
                     RefNo = _employerdetails.Refno,
                     Surname = _employerdetails.Surname,
                     TradingName = _employerdetails.TradingName,
                     CompanyRegistrationNumber = _employerdetails.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                     PhysicalAddress = _employerdetails.BusAddr1,
                     PostalAddress = _employerdetails.BusPostalAddr1,
                     Status = _employerdetails.Status,
                     SETACode = _employerdetails.SetaCode,
                     TransactionDate = ( from _lasttransaction in _entities.LevyTransactions
                                         where OrgId  ==_employerdetails.Id
                                         select _lasttransaction.TransactionDate).Max()
                 });
```

Comment: Tripathis How can I call _lasttransaction outside because is declared inside TransactionDate. Can you show me an example please.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep `_lasttransaction.OrgId` in appropriate variable

(by converting :  **as it is string I would prefer `TryParse`  instead of direct converting  EG : `Int64.TryParse( string , Int64)`),

just before this query and then use this variable in LINQ query instead of using property of `lasttransaction` directly as it is causing problem while converting in Long from string

Answer (score -1):

```
var query = (from _employerdetails in _entities.Organisations
                 select new EmployerDetails
                 {
                     Id = _employerdetails.Id,
                     RefNo = _employerdetails.Refno,
                     Surname = _employerdetails.Surname,
                     TradingName = _employerdetails.TradingName,
                     CompanyRegistrationNumber = _employerdetails.CompanyRegistrationNumber,
                     PhysicalAddress = _employerdetails.BusAddr1,
                     PostalAddress = _employerdetails.BusPostalAddr1,
                     Status = _employerdetails.Status,
                     SETACode = _employerdetails.SetaCode,
                     TransactionDate = _entities.LevyTransactions.Where(x=> Convert.ToInt64(x.OrgId) == _employerdetails.id).Select(y=> y.TransactionDate).Max()
                 });
```

Comment: It give me the same error. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression